# Group files from a directory to another directory with a particular pattern in filename

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

So I have a directory (D:\Project\Archive) having a lot of .txt files with different filename patterns, except for the last 9 characters, before the extension.
I'm listing down 6 filenames as an example:

- 123456_HTQB_1412.txt
- abcd_GGTL_7642.txt
- 1a2b3_HTQB_1412.txt
- pikachu_JTYU_7177.txt
- hsbhsd_GGTL_7642.txt
- yt7777_HTQB_7642.txt

These files are in no particular order.
What is obvious is that the last 9 characters of the filename, before the extension follows a pattern of 4 characters, followed by a underscore, followed by 4 digits. These 9 characters will be same for several files.

My goal is to archive the files having the same 9 characters, regardless of the number of files. The name of the zip file should be the 9 characters with the pattern, and the filenames should be without these 9 characters. The above example should create 3 archive files:

- HTQB_1412.zip - containing 123456_.txt, 1a2b3_.txt, yt7777_.txt.
- GGTL_7642.zip - containing abcd_.txt, hsbhsd_.txt.
- JTYU_7177.zip - containing pikachu_.txt.

The approach I've taken for the grouping is to extract the pattern of the first filename, move the file to the directory _toArchive, and then loop through the rest of the files to check for the same pattern. If it matches, then move it to the directory _toArchive, and continue till it reaches the end of the inner loop. The script will then traverse to _toArchive, and zip the files. Then the control returns to the first loop to repeat the same operation on the remaining files.

The issue that I'm facing is mainly with the grouping. Even though the logic works fine, but with the enabling of delayed expansion, the variables still hold the values even after the files have been moved to the other directory. This is causing unnecessary overhead, resulting in 'File not found' error messages, when the loop is trying to access those files. Is there any way to unset the variables by using arrays? Or any other approach that might be easier than the one that I'm using?

I'm just posting the code for the grouping operations, because once this is figured out, I'll be able to implement the rest.

```
set WORKDIR=D:\Project\Archive
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%g in ('dir /b %WORKDIR%\*.txt') do (
    set firstFile=%%~ng
    set firstPattern=!firstFile:~-9!
    move /y %WORKDIR%\%%g %WORKDIR%\_toArchive
    call :checkPatterns
)
:checkPatterns
    for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /b %WORKDIR%\*.txt') do (
        set fileToGroup=%%i
        set groupedFile=%%~ni
        set groupedPattern=!groupedFile:~-9!
        call :groupPatterns
    )
:groupPatterns
    if "%groupedPattern%" == "%firstPattern%" (
        move /y %WORKDIR%\%fileToGroup% %WORKDIR%\_toArchive
    )
```

Comment: You have to seperate the called subroutines from normal program flow with a `Goto :Eof` in a line in front  of the `:label`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to take a different approach:

- iterate all files and build an environment (array) variable for each group
- iterate the groups and move (or copy) files (with shorted names) to a group - folder
- zip the files inside the group folder and afterwards delete the group folder

The following batch requires 7zip to be reachable somewhere in the path:

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\01\14\SO_54189436.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set WORKDIR=D:\Project\Archive

:: clear Group[] variables
for /f "delims==" %%A in ('Set Group[ 2^>Nul') Do set "%%A="

:: get groups
for /f "tokens=*" %%g in ('dir /b %WORKDIR%\*.txt') do (
    set FileName=%%~ng
    set "Group[!FileName:~-9!]=!FileName:~-9!"
)
set Group[
:: procss groups
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%A in ('Set Group[ 2^>Nul') Do (
  MD "%WORKDIR%\%%A" 1>Nul 2>&1
  for %%B in ("%WORKDIR%\*%%A.txt") Do Call :MoveRenFile "%%A" "%%B"
  Rem zip files and delete group folder
  PushD "%WORKDIR%\%%A"
  7z a "..\%%A.zip" *
  PopD
  RD /S /Q "%WORKDIR%\%%A" 
)

Goto :Eof
:MoveRenFile
Set "File=%~nx2"
set "NewName=%WORKDIR%\%~1\!File:_%~1=!"
Echo Move "%~2" "%NewName%"
     Move "%~2" "%NewName%" >NUL
Goto :Eof
```

Intermediate result with files renamed and stored in group folders:

```
> tree %Workdir% /F
└───Project
    └───Archive
        ├───GGTL_7642
        │       abcd.txt
        │       hsbhsd.txt
        │
        ├───HTQB_1412
        │       123456.txt
        │       1a2b3.txt
        │
        ├───HTQB_7642
        │       yt7777.txt
        │
        └───JTYU_7177
                pikachu.txt
```

End result with zip files:

```
> tree /F D:\
D:\
└───Project
    └───Archive
            GGTL_7642.zip
            HTQB_1412.zip
            HTQB_7642.zip
            JTYU_7177.zip
```